# Why doesn't PostgreSQL look up by PK first (when `WHERE` contains a condition on the PK, but also on other columns)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

When I run the following query against my PostgreSQL DB (where the `id` column on the `courses` table is the primary key, and there's also an index on `is_deleted`, which is a boolean):

```sql
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT c.title
FROM courses AS c
WHERE c.id = 1 AND NOT (c.is_deleted)
LIMIT 1
```

This is the query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=4.15..6.17 rows=1 width=318) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on courses c  (cost=4.15..6.17 rows=1 width=318) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT is_deleted) AND (id = 1))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2
        Heap Blocks: exact=2
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_courses_is_deleted  (cost=0.00..4.14 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=6 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (is_deleted = false)
Planning Time: 0.179 ms
Execution Time: 0.068 ms
```

Unless I'm misinterpreting this (which is entirely possible because I'm totally new to this), it's basically filtering by `is_deleted` FIRST instead of simply doing a lookup using the PK and its index. This doesn't make sense, wouldn't it be more efficient if it simply did a `Index Scan using pk_courses on courses`?!

Comment: It's an almost empty table, maybe analyze didn't run yet and the statistics are not updated. But any other plan would be just as fast. Create a couple of million records, run analyze and try again.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL estimates that using the index on `is_deleted` is about as efficient as the primary key index. In such a case, it prefers the smaller index.

But the question is academic. Since you had to disable sequential scans to get PostgreSQL to use an index at all, most likely because the table is tiny, PostgreSQL considers index scans inefficient in this case. Like you wouldn't consult an inventory to pick one of the five books on the shelf above your bed.